# Source to Source Translator or Custom Interpreter?

Tags: compiler-construction, lua, code-translation

So, I'm wondering if anyone has had any thoughts (hopefully based on experience) on the merits of building a source to source translator vs. building a custom interpreter.  I'm working on a project that interprets mathematical functions and so far I've relied on utilizing Lua to do my dirty work.  I'm now at the point where I need to either modify the input string supplied by the user or build an interpreter for my DSL (e.g., I want to add custom functionality such that you can slice arrays like x[1:2] which is not possible in Lua - so I'd modify that to be something like range(x, 1, 2) [just as an example]).

I'm also concerned about future extensibility.  I'd like to allow people to define their own functions in Lua, so I'm not sure how I'd incorporate that if I built a custom interpreter.  So if anyone has any good reading materials on source to source translators and/or building a custom VM / interpreter that has the ability to call Lua functions, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: A few people on Lua mailing list are actively developing mathematical stuff with Lua. Consider to drop a line for some insights.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Metalua](http://metalua.luaforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Lua, you can also generate Lua bytecode instead of Lua source. The downside is that bytecode is not portable, though.